# Finding text whether it is highlighted or not

Tags: python, pdf-generation, pypdf

I am currently trying to use `PyPDF2` to read the PDF file in the `Python`.I want to know whether the text of the PDF file is highlighted or not.

**Context:**

We use to  highlight text in PDF file with a different color.Is there any way to know which text is highlighted in **Python** using any library or so?
If there is please direct me to the right source.

I look into many places for this problem.What I found is `PyPDF2` can't solve this problem?

Comment: I am also looking for same.

Answer (score 0):

In PyPdf2, you can use get a pageObject which is a dictionary. You can then search for key = '/Annots' and its values in it. You can at least know whether page is having highlighted text or not.